# Dimension of a vector space when sum and multiplication changes

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If a vector space over the complex numbers has dimension $n$, can we change the definitions of sum and multiplication by complex numbers so that the dimension changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, then the answer is yes, as long as the dimension is nonzero and at most $\mathfrak c$ (the cardinality of the continuum $= \lvert {\bf R}\rvert=\lvert {\bf C}\rvert$).

This is because if $1\leq \dim V\leq \mathfrak c$, then $\lvert V\rvert=\mathfrak c$, so you can take any $W$ of dimension between $1$ and $\mathfrak c$ (distinct from $\dim V$) and fix a bijection $\varphi\colon V\to W$ and transport the linear structure from $W$ to $V$ using $\varphi$, and then $V$ with this structure will be obviously isomorphic to $W$ and hence have dimension $\dim W$.

If the dimension is $0$ then it obviously can't be done, if it's greater than $\mathfrak c$, then $\dim V=\lvert V\rvert$, so it can't be done, either.